# 'Plate/tile hybrids' (plates with studs missing)

Tags: part-database

I wonder whether a piece exists fitting any of the following (equivalent) descriptions:

- As a 1x2 jumper (two-studs-to-one-stud-jumper) or a 1x3 jumper (three-studs-to-two-studs-jumper), but without the 0.5 stud offset.
- As a 1x2 or 1x3 plate, but with one stud missing.
- Ax a 1x1 or 1x2 plate 'stuck to' a single 1x1 tile.

EDIT: the intended use was to attach the 'hair' for a Bionicle MOC representing a character of the  [Vortixx](https://biosector01.com/wiki/Vortixx) race. I planned to build the head using a [Vahki head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47332&name=Bionicle%20Head%20Connector%20Block%20(Vahki)) with a [one-axle-two-pins perpendicular connector](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42003&name=Technic,%20Axle%20and%20Pin%20Connector%20Perpendicular%203L%20with%202%20Pin%20Holes) [attached to the axle hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32062&name=Technic,%20Axle%202%20Notched) on the back of the head, then attach the tile/plate-hybrids I described to the connector's pin holes with their studs, and finally 'loop' three [system chains](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30104&name=Chain%2021%20Links%20(16-17L)&category=%5BChain%5D#T=P) between the now-exposed stud holes. Currently I'm leaning towards just using two 1x3 jumpers and living with the half-stud of open space.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, this part does not exis.

In addition to the part suggest by Michael, you might be able to use the [2x2 tile with 2 studs (33909)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/33909/tile-special-2-x-2-with-only-2-studs/) if your design could be adjusted to make use of a 2x2 part:

[image: 2x2 tile with two studs]

Answer (score 6):

No, those parts currently do not exist. There does however exist a 1x4 plate with the middle studs missing: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=172557#T=C

[image]

Perhaps tell us the application you have in mind, and we can suggest other existing elements.

Comment: Just a note, this element comes in two versions: 92593 - WITHOUT groove (older type); 41740 - WITH groove (newer version ).